# Rotate to sign not working inside iframe on a mobile device

Tags: iframe, mobile, docusignapi

At the end of our workflow, we submit our insurance document to docusign for embedded signing. When running inside an iframe, rotating the screen does not allow the user to sign with their finger. It still says `rotate to sign`. Due to cross-domain restrictions, we are unable to run our embedded workflow outside of the iframe.

Is there a way to disable drawing signatures on mobile devices, opting instead for simply clicking the signature tabs like on a desktop device.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign recommends NOT using an `iFrame` on Mobile devices and instead using a `Webview` - reason being some of the bug(s) you are running into.

Have you tried using the DocuSign iOS SDK, which automatically creates and handles signing for you in a webview?  It's free to use and open sourced on GitHub:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ios-sdk

Comment: I already know that. I don't have a choice of running outside an iframe, because I don't control the whole site. This is a website, not a native app, so the sdk is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to disable drawing signatures on mobile devices, opting
>   instead for simply clicking the signature tabs like on a desktop
>   device.

Yes.  In the Console go to Preferences -> Features -> Signature Adoption Configuration.  Here you can check the "Disable draw signature" option at the top.

Comment: I can't find that option when I log into docusign. I see "Sending and Signing" but nothing for Signature Adoption Configuration.

Comment: For me it falls under the "Manage Account" heading of the Features page.  I suppose it could depend on account type.

Comment: It depends on account type, it may not be something that you have administration over without contacting DocuSign Support / Your Account Manager